# Reading content of Environment variables dialog

Tags: .net, .net-core

It's a .NET Core 2.2 app. I want to set some Environment Variables in Visual Studio 2017 and then read those variables in .NET code.

I tried:

[image]

But, then when I try reading this from code

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST_ENVIRONMENT")`

the value is always NULL, regardless of using Process, User or Machine target.

Is there a way to read the content of the Environment Variables dialog from .NET Core code?

Thanks.

Comment: Use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables

Add NuGet packages

Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 0):

Use `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables`

GitHub project: [env-core3](https://github.com/hack2root/env-core3)

Add NuGet packages

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            var value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TestKey");
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
```

[image: Values from environment configuration]

Answer (score 0):

you can use Environment Variables and from appSettings.json